# При выборе определенного способа доставки - появлялось поле input, как реализовать?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, woocommerce

Мне нужно реализовать такую функцию.
На последнем этапе на странице checkout когда уже виден весь заказ и происходит метод выбора доставки есть выбор метода доставки, реализованный radiobutton http://joxi.ru/DrlzvbXi6qo52P
Как мне сделать так что бы при выборе определенного способа доставки - появлялось поле input?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой пример

**HTML**

```
  <form action="">
        <input type="radio" name="typeDelivery" value="1"> Доставка 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="typeDelivery" value="2"> Доставка 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="typeDelivery" value="3">Доставка 3
        <input id="address" type="text" name="address" value="" style="display:none">
      </form>
```

**JS**

```
(function () {
  "use strict"

  function _deliveryAddress () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input[name=typeDelivery]:radio").change(function () {
        console.log();
        if($(this).val() == 2) {
          $('#address').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $('#address').css('display', 'none');
        }
      });
    });
  }

  return {
    delivery: _deliveryAddress()
  }
}())
```